# 'The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer' error with custom handler in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, .net-maui

I am currently migrating a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI, and I am noticing that to make custom controls it has changed to creating a custom handler. I have followed the documentation values and an article in the .NET MAUI [Wiki](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Porting-Custom-Renderers-to-Handlers) on GitHub but I have come across when making the MapText that when assigning the value that I declare in my interface it throws me the error CS0131 "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer" and this prevents me from continuing.

For the moment I have continued using the classic way to create the custom controls, but since I have already indicated deprecated I have decided to adopt this new way, but the error mentioned above prevents me, in this case not only with a custom Entry, but also with a custom Label.

I would be very grateful for your support

This is my CustomEntryHandler:

```
public partial class CustomEntryHandler : ViewHandler<ICustomEntry, EditText>
{
    private static PropertyMapper<ICustomEntry, CustomEntryHandler> CustomEntryMapper = new(ViewMapper)
    {
        [nameof(ICustomEntry.Text)] = MapText,
    };

    public CustomEntryHandler(CommandMapper commandMapper = null) : base(CustomEntryMapper, commandMapper)
    {
    }

    protected override EditText CreatePlatformView()
    {
        return new EditText(Context);
    }

    private static void MapText(EntryHandler handler, ICustomEntry entry)
    {
        handler.PlatformView?.Text = entry.Text;// This line is the error CS0131
    }
}
```

And this is my interface and Custom Control Class:

```
public interface ICustomEntry : IView
{
    public string Text { get; }
    public Color TextColor { get; }
}

public class CustomEntry : View, ICustomEntry
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Color TextColor { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: it would help a great deal if you told us which line causes the error, as well as the specific error code.  I'm going to assume that it's `handler.PlatformView?.Text` - you can't use a null conditional operator on the left hand of an assignment

Comment: Change your line to `if( handler.PlatformView != null ) handler.PlatformView.Text = entry.Text;`

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to indicate the line, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code:

```
 if(handler.PlatformView != null)
     handler.PlatformView.Text = entry.Text;
```

The null propogation operator returns a value. Since, its on the left hand side and not a value, it cant be use this way.

Someone also opened an issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2883